# How to get classname or props from NavLink to use with google tag manager with react and redux in a stateless functional component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

Pretty new to both react, redux and gtm. I am trying to use google tagmanager and I have a navbar where I want to get the classname of every NavLink in a variable so I can send it along my gtm-event. The reason for this is so that I can put the gtm-event in a click-handler so I don't need to put the full gtm-code in every onClick. Is there a way I can get the classnames from Navlinks in this stateless functional component? In the example below I have only put a gtm-event in one of the Navlinks (for readability), but my mission is to have one in every NavLinks. Let me know if you have any questions. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
    const intl = useIntl();
    const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.token !== null);
    const locale = useSelector(state => state.common.locale);
    const user = useSelector(state => state.user.user);

    return (
        <StyledCategoryNav>
            <div className="shadow" />
            <div className="wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink
                            exact
                            to={`/${locale}/lobby`}
                            className="lobby"
                            onClick={() => {
                                TagManager.dataLayer({
                                    dataLayer: {
                                        event: 'open_category',
                                        locale: locale,
                                        userId: isEmpty(user) ? null : user.UserID,
                                        clicked: [Variable that takes the clicked buttons classname]
                                    }
                                });
                            }}
                        >
                            <HomeIcon />
                            {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'categories.lobby' })}
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    {isAuthenticated && (
                        <li>
                            <NavLink
                                exact
                                to={`/${locale}/lobby/new`}
                                className='new'
                        >
                                {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'categories.new' })}
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    )}
                    <li>
                        <NavLink exact to={`/${locale}/lobby/recommended`}
                        className='recommended'
                        >
                            {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'categories.recommended' })}
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </StyledCategoryNav>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target.className` should do the trick.

Make sure to use `activeClassName` and not `className` because with `NavLink`, when the route is matched, react-router will add a class called `active`, so in such case your class name will be a string of classes separated by spaces.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-gtm-get-class-name-eskod)

```js
<NavLink
    exact
    to={`/${locale}/lobby`}
    activeClassName="lobby"
    onClick={(e) => {
        TagManager.dataLayer({
            dataLayer: {
                event: 'open_category',
                locale: locale,
                userId: isEmpty(user) ? null : user.UserID,
                clicked: e.target.className //<----here
            }
        });
    }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

send a classname in router param and get that param from another page simple. If need more help let me know.

ex:
{isAuthenticated && (

<NavLink
exact
to={`/${locale}/lobby/new?**classname="class-name**"`}
className='new'
>
{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'categories.new' })}

)}

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. I think you misunderstand so I'm gonna try to explain it again. I want to save the className of the buttons as a variable so I can use it in Google tagmanager. So if that variable was called "categoriesClassName" I would use it here:

    onClick={() => {
         TagManager.dataLayer({
                     dataLayer: {
                              event: 'open_category',
                              clicked: categoryClassName
                                 }
                        });

Comment: save classnames in store and get that values as props. Use React-redux